# Check if a pair of values appears in a range

Tags: excel, vba, range, key-value

So what I need to do is basically this:

I have a few pair of numbers that are conflicting and a range in Excel where I need to check if I have these pair of numbers appears

e.g

Conflicting numbers: 1 and 2

Range to check

1
3
4
8
2

In this case, since the two conflicting numbers appears in the range, I need to identify it.

Since I'm pretty new to VBA language, I dont even know where to begin

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Why using VBA?

Is not enough the Excel formula

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(HLOOKUP(G1;A1:E1;1;FALSE));ISNUMBER(HLOOKUP(H1;A1:E1;1;FALSE)));"conflicting";"NOT conflicting")
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have more than 1 pair of numbers that needs to be checked. That is why I thought VBA would be more useful with this.

Also the ranges where I need to do the verification are in displayed vertically

Comment: So you need a procedure that takes a selected range and ask the user for a pair of numbers, answering if both are in the range. Is that correct?